# Task Board Management with BuddyPress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress, taskmanager

I am presently working in a WordPress Project with BuddyPress & BBPress.
In that project I have a requirement where

1: User A can post a task to be done. 2: User B can accept that task to be done. 3: When User B finished whatever was requested in the task, they mark the task as done and User A gets a notification.

** All This to be done within the group (or forum) User A belongs to & Must in the Front End.

I was trying this with the CollabPress plugin. But The problem is that CollabPress Shows the project in the front end but when I click on it then it shows that the page does not exists.

Please give me some Idea how to fix this error and how to customize CollabPress.

Comment: I have further checked to solve this problem... Surprisingly I found that on the front end (in the groups tab) it is not creating the correct hyperlink.

Comment: The created hyper link is: '/groups/it//abc/ ' (say 'abc' is a project). but this should be '/groups/it/projects/abc/ ' (as 'projects' is the tab name). And when I manually go to '/groups/it/projects/abc/ ' then it is working absolutely fine....

Comment: Please some one help me out how to solve it??